# Swift - Accesing values in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I am having trouble accessing values in an array I have made:

```
var words = [[], [], ["test 1", "test 2"], []]
print(words[2])
```

which returns: ["test 1", "test 2"]

I have tried doing:

```
print(words[2[2]])
```

but this returns: Type 'Int' has no subscript members

I essentially want to get "test 1" or "test 2", as when needed

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `print(words[2][1])` instead? In others words: `let w2 = words[2]`, that's `["test 1", "test 2"]`.  So `w2[0]` is `"test 1"` and `w2[1]` is `"test 2"`. So by concatenation: `print(words[2][0])` or `print(words[2][1])`

Comment: `words[2[2]]`?????

Answer (score 0):

```
 var words = [[], [], ["test 1", "test 2"], []]
 print(words[2])  // ["test 1", "test 2"]
 print(words[2][1])  // test 2
```

You can use 2D array the above way..